# How can I change dialog title color in jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have something like this:

```
$div = $('<div id="error" title="Error">');
$div.append('<p>Hi</p>');

$div.dialog({
    modal: true,
    maxHeight:500,
});
```

Can i change background color of dialog title somehow like this?:

```
 $div.dialog({
        modal: true,
        maxHeight:500,
    }).find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Doubt it, there will be a style that is overriding whatever it is you are setting it to. My advice would be to find what that style it, create another one that is named differently and replace it in your jquery.

Comment: Themeroller?: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: @Gjohn - Inline styles override css styles, so this change should work.  milandjukic88 - the easiest way to see if code you've designed works is to try it.  :-P

Comment: @Gjohn I have multiple dialog's on page opened. I want only one to be changed. With your way, is this can be done?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I'm trying and it's not working :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `prev()` instead of `find()` because that element is not inside `$div`:

```
$div.dialog({
    modal: true,
    maxHeight:500,
}).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background","red");
```

Also I use `background` to override all other elements like `background-image`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Ad7nF/

Comment: Hey .. how can I add background color and background border in above example?

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni try instead of .css() method adding a class with .addClass()

Answer (score 24):

Another method to do is to :

Define your styling class - myTitleClass

Define the css as

```
  . myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar {
          background:red;
    }
```

and add the custom class to the dialog initialization function :

```
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'myTitleClass'
     });
```

JSFiddle - (but with another sample code)

http://jsfiddle.net/khVYj/3/

Comment: I think this is the best answer, as it allows multiple dialogs with different css without having to resort to change it on the fly.

Comment: This approach allows changing every single dialog design while leaving the complexity in the CSS files. Not only, as Zak mentioned, you can have multiple styles simply by changing the class name, but you can also offer completely different design and color choice simply by changing the source CSS file. This answer presents the best approach I found so far.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way is this: -

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
      background:red;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it will force you to have the same background on every dialog oin your page. I think @user1428716 answer's is the best approach.